# Optimize at will dpr

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

I always hear about insane nova builds that can drop Orcus in a round (at least before errata), but it seems these builds rely on encounter and daily powers. How could you get stupid damage from At-Wills?

I've seen a level 30 ranger build to do up to 200 dpr at will, but what about heroic tier? The closest thing I know of is the essentials rogue spamming tactical trick and sneak attack, but that relies on mobility and positioning: lose one or the other, and he's completely sunk. At first level, he could do max dpr of around 25-30 damage. That's pretty good, from experience playing it.

So any others in heroic tier?

Comment: Are you looking for specific classes? check out the Wizards Char Op boards they are flat out awesome for this sort of stuff. Or are you just looking for the Heroic tier At-Will DPR king?

Comment: Both, actually, and curious as to whether any high dpr builds scale thru all 3 tiers.

Comment: Go look at the DPR King thread on the builds http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22105109/DPR_King_Candidates_2.0 Any post I make would just be restating that.

Answer (score 5):

**Build for charge, then take charge enhancing items**

There are some excellent charge items out there that make an at-will MBA or MBA equivalent better than encounter or daily all encounter long. Most of the [DPR King](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22105109/DPR_King_Candidates_2.0) builds rely on that or multi-attacks combined with high static modifiers like from wintertouched and lasting frost.

Comment: I had a beastform focused druid who did something like this.  If you can manage via one method or another to use some of your at-wills as MBA's for purposes of charging (or just in general) you can get some nice effects to go with your damage.

Comment: note that this link appears to have died along with WoTC support for that forum.